# How to parse txt to list as symbols in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm still new in Clojure; I'm trying to split the values parsed from txt file,

I need to add these words to the list as sembol. For example

Example txt file:

> this is a simple test

and the result should be the following:

```
'((t h i s) (i s) (a) (s i m p l e) (t e s t)
```

please some help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please stop defacing your question. That's not how this site works.

Comment: You asked for Clojure code, not Python code. Editing your question to ask about Python now that there are answers is not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to call [split](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split) to get the words of a string. Then, for each word you need to iterate and convert the characters to symbols. It is easiest to iterate using the [for](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) macro. You can convert a character to string using [str](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/str) and convert the string to symbol using [symbol](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/symbol).

```
(defn line-to-lists [line]
  (for [word (clojure.string/split (clojure.string/trim line) #"\s+")]
    (for [char word] (symbol (str char)))))

(line-to-lists "this is a simple test")
```

You can get the contents of a file using [slurp](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/slurp) and call the function on it as the following:

```
(line-to-lists (slurp "file.txt"))
```

EDIT: fixed to work with multiple spaces and traling/leading spaces.
EDIT: added string/trim to remove unnecessary whitepages.

Comment: fails for multiple spaces: (line-to-lists "asd{three-spaces}asd") => ((a s d) () () () (a s d)) , and for trailing spaces for example

Comment: @leetwinski thank you, fixed!

Comment: still fails for leading spaces:  (line-to-lists " asd") => (() (a s d)) .. sorry :)

Answer (score 5):

first you need to split a line into words,
and then every word should be mapped with `char->symbol` converting function:

something like this:

```
user> (require '[clojure.string :as cs])
nil

user> (defn to-syms [s]
        (let [words (cs/split (cs/trim s) #"\s+")]
          (map #(map (comp symbol str) %) words)))
#'user/to-syms

user> (to-syms "this is a line")
;;=> ((t h i s) (i s) (a) (l i n e))
```

**UPDATE**

expansion:

first you get all the words from string, splitting it by spaces:

```
(cs/split (cs/trim "aaa  bbb  ccc") #"\s+")
;;=> ["aaa" "bbb" "ccc"]
```

then we need to make up a function that processes the word converting it to a list of symbols. As clojure string is a sequence of characters, you can `map` over it, producing new collection:

```
(defn char->sym [c]
  (symbol (string c))

user> (char->sym \a)
;;=> a

user> (map char->sym "asd")
;;=> (a s d)
;; in my example i use the functional composition: (comp symbol str)
;; that creates the function that works exactly like char->sym

;; let's wrap this mapping to a function:
(defn word->syms [w]
   (map char->sym w))

user> (word->syms "asd")
;;=> (a s d)

;; and now we just have to transform the whole list of words:
user> (map word->syms ["asd" "fgh"])
;;=> ((a s d) (f g h))
```

in addition, to convert the list of symbols to back string you can simply call the `str` function with all list's items as arguments `(apply str '(a s d)) => "asd"`, or use `clojure.string/join` for that: `(clojure.string/join '(a s d)) => "asd"`